# Route only HTTP(S) traffic through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, pptp

I have a ppp0 interface set up as a VPN tunnel using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient#PPTP). Now I need to route traffic on specific ports (80, 443) through the ppp0 interface. Ideally, if the VPN server is down, all the HTTP(S) requests should fail.

There are a lot of answers for similar issues suggesting to use `iptables`, so I guess that's the way the go, but I can't figure out the right commands to use for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Here we shall take `www` as the service for routing. Use `mangle` table of iptable for modifying the `www` packets.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

We are marking all packets with destination port `80` as `0x1` .

Now save and restart `iptables`.

```
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` by just giving an entry

```
100 wwwtable
```

Write rule for `www` packets.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 lookup wwwtable
```

Add route at new table `wwwtable`. All other traffic will go through the
default gateway, which can be seen by `ip route show` command.

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table wwwtable $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `www` packets to table `wwwtable`

```
sudo ip route add default dev ppp0 table wwwtable
```

Use `ip route show table wwwtable` to show all routes at `wwwtable`.

Repeat everything for `https` on port `443`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, however, the first command doesn't seem to work, it returns an error saying `Bad argument '80'`. I'm on 14.04 LTS.

Comment: sorry, typo error. I fix them.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, but it's not working for me. While the routing is changed somehow, it doesn't load websites, all the requests just time out.

BTW: there's another typo in `/etc/iproute2/rt_table`, it should be `rt_tables` and there is no iptables service, at least not on my system. And I think you can specify `--dports 80,443` both at the same time.